# Issue with capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano

I am currently having a git project consisting of multiple projects. My project structure is similar to this

```
=> application-1(rails)
=> application-2
```

I am using capistrano for deployment. Since the home folder does not have Gemfile.lock, capistrano is throwing an error.

> The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.

Is there a way to deploy just a specific folder in the git repository?

Comment: https://github.com/olek/capistrano-multiproject exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403401/826610).

```
set :bundle_gemfile, "app/Gemfile"
```